# SQL Select from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, foreign-keys

I have a database with this schema:

1. Project

   ```
   ProjectId ProjName Costs PStart PFinish  
   Project(ProjectID, Integer, PKEY)
   ```
2. Workpacket

   ```
   WorkpacketID WorkpacketName WStart WFinish 
   Workpacket (WorkpacketID,Integer,PKEY)
   Workpacket got a FKEY ond ProjectID
   ```
3. Employee

   ```
   EmployeeID EmployeeName  EmployeSalary  
   Employee (EmployeeID, Integer, PKEY)
   Employee got a FKEY on ProjectID and WorkpacketID
   ```

Now I want to select a *ProjectID* and get the following information: *ProjectName, WorkpacketID, WorkpacketName, WStart*.

```
Select Project.ProjectID, Project.ProjectName, Workpacket.WorkpacketID,
       Workpacket.WorkpacketName, Workpacket.WStart
from Project, Workpacket
where Project.ProjectID = 1;
```

Is this correct? I don't understand how to use joins here and if joins are necessary cause of the FKEY.

Comment: Which SQL database engine are you using?

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Try to use always explicit joins. Like: `select t.field, j.field from table t join [left or any kind of join] second_table j on (t.key = j.join_criteria)`

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

To join tables there must me a key on which basis the joins are performed.

In your project Table, Projectid is key

in workpacked workpacketId is key

in employee Employee Id is key

but there is no key each table which shows association between these 3 tables

project table should have WorkpackedID and and Workpacked should have employeId to perform a join

Comment: the data he wants is only from first 2 tables and it has a pk and fk, why do you need 3rd table here